# AngularJS updating specific fields with new data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Say, I have the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="postsController">
    <div id = "post_id_{{post.postid}}" class = "post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
        ......
        <div class="comments">
           <div><span>{{post.totalcomments}}</span> Comments</div>
        </div>
        .......
    </div>   
</div>
```

and on page load this evaluates to something like:

```
<div ng-controller="postsController">
    <div id = "post_id_1" class = "post">
        ......
        <div class="comments">
           <div><span>3</span> Comments</div>
        </div>
        .......
    </div>
    <div id = "post_id_2" class = "post">
        ......
        <div class="comments">
           <div><span>6</span> Comments</div>
        </div>
        .......
    </div>
    ....and so on.....
</div>
```

How could I then (using a different controller?) update the DOM when there is a change in the post.totalcomments value for a particular post? I've got the backend worked out, and know you can use $timeout to have a controller repeat itself. I would do it with jQuery (messy but easy) like this (eg: post #1 had a new comment):

```
var newtotal = 4; //but really get the value from ajax call
$("#post_id_1 .comments span").html(newtotal)
```

But how would I do this with Angular? I don't want to re-display all the posts and the data, every time I check for updated with the server. Just have a controller (which refreshes with $timeout) and only update the changed fields as needed.

Thanks

Comment: Are you pushing a new object to the array `posts` - or updating a specific `post`?

Comment: Just a specific post, and (ideally) not monitoring the entire post data. Just a few fields, eg: totalcomments

Comment: Hmm...is the other controller that's updating the info on the same page (child controller) or is it completely separate?

Comment: :) I don't know. I am trying to work out the best way to achieve this with AngularJS. I am trying to migrate something from jQuery. I haven't started making another controller.

Comment: Well, if everything can be in the same controller, update the `post` at the right index of the `posts` array and it will auto bind to your view. If there's a data call when someone updates, post the call

Comment: Ok, sorry I am new to AngularJS. Can you show me an example of how this would be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the data periodically use $interval rather than timeout, If its going to be only once after a certain perios say 10 seconds use $timeout. And you need not write a separate controller for this. This can be done within the same controller.
A simple interval demo for you, 
Sample Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fj6crcHkxm6rkwJT9eGg?p=preview

JS:
    app.controller('MainCtrl1', function($scope, $timeout, $http, $interval) {
      $scope.comments = [{
        total: 3,
        comment: 'some comment 1'
      }, {
        total: 10,
        comment: 'some other comment'
      }];

```
  $interval(function(){
    //logic to update comments
    $scope.comments[0].total++;
  },1000);

  $scope.updateCount = function(){
    $scope.comments[1].total++;
  };

});
```